# Node JS logout function shows error: `onWebTokenError: jwt malformed`

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt

**File:**

routes > auth.js

```
var express = require('express');
var authController = require('../controllers/auth');

var router = express.Router();

//Registration POST
router.post('/register', authController.register);

//Login POST
router.post('/login', authController.login);

//Logout
router.get('/logout', authController.logout);



module.exports = router;
```

**File**

routes > pages.js

```
var express = require('express');
var authController = require = require('../controllers/auth');

var router = express.Router();

//Home page
router.get('/', authController.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
  res.render('index', {
    user: req.user
  });
});

//Register Form
router.get('/register', function(req,res){
  res.render('register');
});

//Login form
router.get('/login', function(req,res){
  res.render('login');
});

router.get('/profile', authController.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){

  if(req.user) {
      res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user
      });
  }

  else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }


});


module.exports = router;
```

**File**

controllers > auth.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var { promisify } = require('util');

//database connection
var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
});

exports.login = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    var {email, password} = req.body;

    if(!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).render('login', {
        message: 'Please provide an email and password'
      });
    }

    db.query('select * from users where email = ?', [email], async function(error, results){
      console.log(results)

      if(!results.length || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))){
        res.status(401).render('login', {
          message: 'The email or password is incorrect'
        });
      }
      else{
        var id = results[0].id;
        var token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRECT, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
        });

        console.log("The token is: " + token);

        var cookieOptions = {
          expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
          ),
          httpOnly: true
        }

        res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
        res.status(200).redirect("/");
      }
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

exports.register = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  //Taking values from HTML Register page
  var {name, email, password, passwordConfirm} = req.body;

  db.query("select email from users where email = ?", [email], async function(error, results) {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    if(results.length > 0){
      return res.render('register', {
        message: 'That email is already taken'
      })
    } else if(password !== passwordConfirm) {
      return res.render('register', {
        message: 'Password do not match'
      })
    }

    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    db.query('insert into users set ?', {email: email, name: name, password: hashedPassword}, function(error, result){
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      else{
        console.log(results);
        return res.render('register', {
          message: 'User registered'
        });
      }
    })


  });



}

exports.isLoggedIn = async function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.cookies);
  if(req.cookies.jwt) {
    try {
      var decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt, process.env.JWT_SECRECT);

      console.log(decoded);

      //Check if the user still exists
      db.query('Select * from users where id = ?', [decoded.id], function(error, result) {

        if(!result) {
          return next();
        }

        req.user = result[0];
        return next();

      } );
    }



    catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  else{
      next();
  }
}


exports.logout = async function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('jwt', 'logout', {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true
  });

  res.status(200).redirect('/');
}
```

**File**

.env

```
DATABASE = TEST
DATABASE_HOST = someserver
DATABASE_USER = username
DATABASE_PASSWORD = password
JWT_SECRECT = mysupersecretpassword
JWT_EXPIRES_IN = 90d
JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES = 90
```

**Issue:**

Everything works fine expect the `logout` in controllers > auth.js.

What the logout should do - it should overwrite the cookie to expiry in 5 seconds and redirect me to homepage.

What the logout currently does is shows me this error:

```
onWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at module.exports (C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:63:17)
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at internal/util.js:296:12
    at exports.isLoggedIn (C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\controllers\auth.js:111:48)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Coding\Node JS\Login System\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

I am following a tutorial on SkillShare - I am on my final part and ran into this error and not sure how to solve it.

**Question**

What is the error? How can I fix it?

And also, how can I understand from the error output what that error means?

Comment: You have `isLoggedIn` middleware on `GET /profile` route, which I assume to check jwt validity, and get the user, but error is thrown by the jwt library because the verification failed, what's the result of `console.log(req.cookies);` ?

Comment: The result of `console.log(req.cookies);` is `{ jwt: 'logout' }`

Comment: That's why it throws an error, the `jwt` should contains jwt token, do you see the correct token being logged when logging in? (from `console.log("The token is: " + token);`)

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user go to `/logout`, you set the jwt value to `"logout"`, not deleting it.

```js
exports.logout = async function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('jwt', 'logout', {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true
  });

  res.status(200).redirect('/');
}
```

thus whenever user access a route with `isLoggedIn` middleware, your express app will still detects the user as logged in

```js
exports.isLoggedIn = async function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.cookies);
  if(req.cookies.jwt) { // this still returns true, because you set the jwt cookies to "logout"
     // ...
  }
```

Instead of setting the jwt value to logout, delete it like this:

```js
res.clearCookie('jwt');
```

so your logout controller will look like this:

```js
exports.logout = async function(req, res) {
  res.clearCookie('jwt');
  res.status(200).redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just want to thank you for the nice explanation, just fixed my problem as well. I gave an upvote to the answer.